# How to use paste command for many files whose names are not numbers? (paste columns from each file to one file)

Tags: shell-script, command-line, paste

To paste many files, whose names are incremental numbers:

```
paste {1..8}| column -s $'\t' -t
```

- What if your files wasn't named by number, but only words?
- It can be up to ten files, what should I do?

In addition, you have a list of files that contains all the files you want.

So far, my approach is:

```
mkdir paste
j=0; while read i; do let j+=1; cp $i/ paste/$j; done<list;
cd paste; paste {1..8}| column -s $'\t' -t
```

I have no problem with this approach, I just want to ask if there is any shorter one.

---

Actually my files have the same name, just on different locations, for instance `1MUI/PQR/A/sum, 2QHK/PQR/A/sum, 2RKF/PQR/A/sum`. The `paste` command should be `paste {list}/PQR/A/sum`. The list file is:

```
1MUI
2QHK
2RKF
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `bash` 4

```
mapfile -t <list
paste "${MAPFILE[@]}" | column -s $'\t' -t
```

for the `paste {list}/PQR/A/sum` version of the question

```
mapfile -t <list
paste "${MAPFILE[@]/%//PQR/A/sum}" | column -s $'\t' -t
```

Comment: I have edited my question, sorry for the inconvenience. Please come back and see. When I use this way, the output is `paste: 1MUI: Is a directory` (repeat till the end of the list) and only `cat` one file.

Comment: @Ooker, see the edit

Comment: also, can you explain to me what the `/%/` means?

Comment: @Ooker, that is used to add a suffix to every element of the `MAPFILE` array, for details refer [this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073)

Answer (score 0):

If all your files is in single directory, just use:

```
paste * | column -s $'\t' -t
```

If you have a list file contains all files, and each file name in one line, does not have special characters like space, you can try:

```
paste $(printf "%s " $(cat list)) | column -s $'\t' -t
```

**Updated**

With your updated information, you can try:

```
paste */PQR/A/sum | column -s $'\t' -t
```

If your parent directory contains many files and directory that you don't need, you must list all your directory explicitly:

```
paste {1MUI,2QHK,2RKF,...}/PQR/A/sum | column -s $'\t' -t
```

Comment: wow, you update your answer before I comment. Thanks a lot. Nevertheless, my folder contains more files and folders which don't relevant to my need, therefore I can't use `*`.

Comment: so basically there is no way to shorten my code?

Comment: How is `$(printf "%s " $(cat list))` any better than `$(cat list)`? (They both fail if filenames containing whitespace are present.)