# Paste all files in directory column-wise by last modification order

Tags: bash, files, paste

I am looking to combine all files in a directory (each having one column) into a single file with multiple columns. However, I need the files to be pasted by last modification time order, i.e. in the new file, the first column will come from the oldest file and the last column from the newest file.

I cannot change the names of the original files to reflect this time order. I have used the command [raised and answered in this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/141571/how-to-use-paste-command-for-many-files-whose-names-are-not-numbers-paste-colu) but it doesn't quite do what I need because '*' is not intelligent to file time ordering.

```
paste * | column -s $'\t' -t > output.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

In the `zsh` shell, the gobbing qualifier `om` sorts the entries that a filename globbing pattern expands to in `mtime` timestamp order (most recently modified files first; use `O` in place of `o` to sort in the opposite order).  The globbing qualifier `.` (a dot) would restrict the matching of the globbing pattern to only regular files.

Thus, the globbing pattern `*(.om)` would expand to the visible names of regular files in the current directory, sorted by the `mtime` timestamp.

From the `bash` shell:

```bsh
zsh -c 'paste ./*(.om)' | column -s $'\t' -t >output.txt
```

By default, if the pattern does not match anything, this is treated as an error by the `zsh` shell (as if the `failglob` shell option was set in the `bash` shell).

Note that you may want to write the `output.txt` file to some other directory, or be more specific in the globbing pattern used, as to not pick up the output file name.  The following would explicitly be avoiding the `output.txt` name with a modified globbing pattern:

```bsh
zsh -o extended_glob -c 'paste ./(^output.txt)(.om)' | columns -s $'\t' -t >output.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

To sort filenames by last-modified time:

```bsh
stat -c '%Y %n' * | sort -n | cut -d " " -f 2-
```

This doesn't handle filenames containing newline characters.

So:

```bsh
# read the sorted filenames into an array
mapfile -t files < <(stat -c '%Y %n' * | sort -n | cut -d " " -f 2-)

# then paste the files together
paste "${files[@]}" | ...
```

Comment: Recent versions of GNU Coreutils stat have a `--printf` that allows null termination, and recent versions of bash mapfile can read null delimited input - so you *could* make it handle files with newlines in that case, as `mapfile -d '' -t files < <(stat --printf '%Y\t%n\0' * | sort -zn | cut -z -f 2-)` for example on suitably recent GNU-based systems

Answer (score 2):

You can order the list of files passed to `paste` first:

```
paste $(ls -t) | column -s $'\t' -t
```

`ls -t` will return the files sorted "by modification time, newest first"

`paste` simply parses the files in the order specified on the command line.

Comment: Unfortunately, this relies on parsing the output of `ls`, which is [a bad idea in most cases](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead).